# How to get select box option value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

How to get the value of option select box in jQuery if I have the code like this,

```
<select id='media' name='media'>
    <option value='1'>media1</option>
    <option value='2'>media2</option>
    <option value='3'>media3</option>
</select>
```

When I code for on change event,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#media").change(function()
    {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        alert(id); return false;
    });
});
```

It gives me `media1`,`media2`,`media3` instead of `1, 2, 3`

How to get the value 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Your code should work as is. [And it does.](http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/CFAca/) (Why have you tagged the question with "jquery-ajax"? Is there more code or context to this that you don't show?)

Comment: Confirm, this code works as you want

Comment: Refer this Link, [Jquery-Option](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/22/jquery-get-the-selected-option-text/)

Comment: Use this in if condition. **$("option[value='1']").attr('selected','selected');**. you will get exact value

Answer (score 33):

```
$("#id option:selected").val();
```

Here `id` is the id of a select box. I'm sure it will work 100%.

If you want selected text use this one:

```
$("#id option:selected").text();
```

Comment: option:selected is not required... jQuery support **$("#id").val()** too.

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#media').change(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

this should work the way you want it should.

Comment: That's essentially what the OP already has isn't it? (Except without storing the value in a variable before alerting it.)

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#media').change(function(e) {

        var id = $(this,':selected').val();
        alert(id);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use latest jquery because its working fine

http://jsfiddle.net/Hayhv/

check it give value of option

Answer (score 2):

I did so,

```
<select id='coprede' name='cop_rede'>
<option value='1'>Cop Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value='2'>Cop Nordeste</option>
    <option value='3'>Cop Vitoria</option>
    <option value='4'>Cluster Norte</option>
    <option value='5'>Cluster Centro Oeste</option>
</select>
```

within the script:

```
$(function(){

$('#coprede').change(function(){
    alert($('#coprede :selected').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
$('#media').change(function(){
    alert($('#media :selected').val());// or $('#media').val();        
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of id like this..

```
<select class='media' name='media'>
    <option value='1'>media1</option>
    <option value='2'>media2</option>
    <option value='3'>media3</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".media").live("change",function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        alert(id); return false;
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and its works ok for me make sure about id #media does repeat from other control. Because its config and get value from last find html control