# How to check text box value and select box value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have two fields select box and text box how to compare these two box values?

Text box like:

```
<input type="text" name="u_position" value="<?php echo $row->role_des;?>" style="border:none;" readonly>

And Select box like:

    <select class="form-control" placeholder="designation" value="<?php echo set_value('design');?>" name="design" required>
        <option value="">--Select---</option>
        <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
        <option value="Salessupervisor">Sale Supervisor</option>
    </select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

compare on button click . Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to compare value only when you change select box option ?!!

Comment: compare in php or javascript??

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please include either the php or js code you wrote that isn't working.

Comment: @YashParekh java script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get select box option value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489527/how-to-get-select-box-option-value-in-jquery)

Comment: @Shambu, check my answer. I think that is what you need.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay sir i have two more text box ,how to compare this text box and this select box

Comment: @Shambu, I have updated my answer for three input box.

Comment: @Shambu You can compare any number of variables in the code snippet which I have written below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="u_position" value="<?php echo $row->role_des;?>" style="border:none;" readonly>

    And Select box like:

        <select class="form-control" placeholder="designation" value="<?php echo set_value('design');?>" name="design" required>
            <option value="">--Select---</option>
            <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
            <option value="Salessupervisor">Sale Supervisor</option>
        </select>
    <button type="submit" onclick="checkVals();return false;"  class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

and this is javascript:

```
function checkVals() {
    var a = $('input[name="u_position"]').val();
    var b = $('.form-control').find(":selected").val();
    console.log('this is selected: ' + b + ' ---- and this is text input: ' + a)
    if (a === b) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change',function(){
        if($(this).val() == $('input:eq(0)').val() == $('input:eq(1)').val() == $('input:eq(2)').val())
        {
              //You can do your further code here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Include an onchange attribute in the select element, which would call a javascript function. On the function call, access the textbox element through it's ID and implement your logic.

The HTML code:

```
<input id="textBoxId" type="text" name="u_position" value="<?php echo $row->role_des;?>" style="border:none;" readonly>


<select class="form-control" placeholder="designation" value="<?php echo set_value('design');?>" name="design" required onchange="compareVal(this.value)">
    <option value="">--Select---</option>
    <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
    <option value="Salessupervisor">Sale Supervisor</option>
</select>
```

The Javascript code:

```
function compareVal(param)
{
    if(param == $('#textBoxId').val())
    {
        //Your logic here...
    }
}
```